# Python - Attribute error, 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python

So I have a program that reason a lines file and prints out any errors to stderr.

```
for line in lines_file:
    #get offset up to start of coordinates
    start = re.compile('\s*line\s*')
    m = start.match(line)
    offset = m.end()

    try:
        for i in range(4):
            xy = re.compile('\s*([-]?[0-9]{1,3})\s*')

            if xy.match(line,offset):
                m = xy.match(line,offset)
            else:
                raise Exception

            coordinate = m.group(1)

            if int(coordinate) > 250 or int(coordinate) < -250:
                raise Exception

            offset = m.end()

        end = re.compile('\s*$')
        if not end.match(line,offset):
            raise Exception

    except Exception as e:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Error in line ' + str(line_number) + ":"
        print >> sys.stderr, " " * 4 + line,
        print >> sys.stderr, " " * (offset + 4) + "^"
        line_number = line_number + 1
        continue
```

And if I put in invalid input lines expecting the invalid lines to be printed to stderr, the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lines_to_svg.py", line 37, in <module>
    offset = m.end()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'end'
```

Because this is a fragment of my code, line 37 is the one that says `offset = m.end()`. So why do I keep getting an attribute error? Here's the code that comes before the for loop above just in case this is causing the error:

```
import sys
import re

# SVG header with placeholders for canvas width and height
SVG_HEADER = "<svg xmlns=\"http:#www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\""" width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\">\n"

# SVG bounding box with placeholders for width and height
SVG_BOUNDING_BOX = "<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\""" style=\"stroke:#000;fill:none\" />\n"

# SVG line with placeholders for x0, y0, x1, y1
SVG_LINE = "<line x1=\"%d\" y1=\"%d\" x2=\"%d\" y2=\"%d\""" style=\"stroke:#000\" />\n"

# SVG footer
SVG_FOOTER = "</svg>"

CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500
CANVAS_WIDTH = 500

# process command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage:", str(sys.argv[0]), "lines_file"
    exit(1)

#open file for reading
try:
    lines_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
except IOError:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Cannot open:", str(sys.argv[1])
    exit(2)

offset = 0
line_number = 1
```

The problem is with `offset = m.end()` but I can't seem to figure out why that's causing the error.

Comment: Looks like you are not showing the code you actually run. The line `offset = m.end()` is inside a `try`- `except` block, therefore, you should the output of your error handler and not the default traceback.

Comment: Well I'm not showing the full output. The first two lines of my output do show the error for the invalid lines but then after that it shows the attribute error.

Comment: Read the traceback. There's only one way to interpret it. Have you learnt how to read tracebacks yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two lines `offset = m.end()` in your code. The problem must be here:

```
m = start.match(line)
offset = m.end()
```

because the other line is in a `try`-`except`block.

You can change it to:

```
m = start.match(line)
if m is not None:
    offset = m.end()
```

and keep the old offset if there was no match, i.e. `m` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`re.match` returns None when no matches was found. You need to check `if m is None` for this case.